# How to enable ssh root access ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ssh, root, remote-access, docker

on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

1. change

   ```
   PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
   ```

   to

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   ```
2. `sudo service ssh restart`

still permission denied

Comment: 16.04 Mine does not have this line.  Simply adding it and restarting the service still doesn't make it work.

Answer (score 10):

on Ubuntu 16.04

1. ensure you have openssh-server server installed 
    sudo apt-get install openssh-server

   sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

   1. change

      PermitRootLogin prohibit-password

   to

   ```
   PermitRootLogin yes
   ```

   or `sudo sed -i 's/prohibit-password/yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

   2. in order to PAM authentication add

      AllowUsers root

   or `sudo echo "AllowUsers root" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

   3. `sudo service ssh restart`

works fine

in order you don't know your root password set new with privileged user

`sudo passwd root`

> and you may want to get rid of password prompt in safe way what may be useful approach for sth like rsync, ansible and so on, so probably

from where ever you want to connect

`ssh-keygen; ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@YOURHOST`

enter the root pass you have just set and DONE

`ssh root@YOURHOST`